# Advantages of attribute key value pattern

Tags: java, hashtable

I have come across this pattern in a Java class quite a few times:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final String firstAttributeKey = "FirstAttribute";
    private static final String secondAttributeKey = "SecondAttribute";
    ...

    private String firstAttributeValue = null;
    private String secondAttributeValue = null;
    ...

    public void setProperty(String key, String value) {
        if(key.equals(firstAttributeKey) {
            firstAttributeValue = value;
        } else if(key.equals(secondAttributeKey) {
            secondAttributeValue = value;
        ...
    }

    public void getProperty(String key, String value) {
        if(key.equals(firstAttributeKey) {
            return firstAttributeValue;
        } else if(key.equals(secondAttributeKey) {
            return secondAttributeValue;
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

This pattern included a long list of key-value pairs. I am wondering what the advantages of such a structure are. In my mind, it seems much easier and more efficient to simply create a hashmap to store the key-value pairs.

Comment: So you are storing only two values, aren't you? and the keys always should be FirstAttribute and SecondAttribute to store value in your structure

Comment: ...well this is just a snippet. There could be 40-50 attributes, all with a key and value declaration, and a set and get statement. I don't understand why you would want such an implementation

Comment: Maybe the author of this code simply didn't know about Maps and tried to reinvent the wheel? Or it's some (probably misguided) attempt to optimize for  performance.

Comment: Using this approach instead of a HashMap looks like pure insanity to me. The only benefit I see that this might offer would be to control the allowed keys - but there are better ways to achieve this even with a HashMap. (I'm assuming the `void` getter is a typo.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the attribute-value pattern to be useful in certain circumstances, such as dealing in aggregate and using collections to store updates, generic UIs that handle any objects that follow the pattern, and persist/restore.

However, the way it is implemented here seems to have none of the benefits and several added drawbacks.

First of all, you look up the field to which the attribute belongs via if/else ladder, which is brittle, computationally expensive, and difficult to maintain. If you have such a general get/set API, you may want to supplement with actual accessors/mutators for each field as well as maintain the general-purpose get/set when generic use is needed.

Second, you get and set attributes based on a string identifier, but have not published what the identifiers are nor what they mean (they are all private). There must be a cleaner way for the caller to coordinate the attributes other than string constants copied throughout your codebase.

Third, if you no longer assume that all attributes are of type `String`, then you should add type information to your attribute, which means using a more complex object than a simple `String` which can pair an identifier with a data type. If you do assume all attributes are `String`, then can be limiting in where the pattern is usable.

To answer your original question though, the hashmap is certainly a more efficient and maintainable run-time construct than the if/else ladder. The only drawbacks are that the hashmap may take slightly more memory to store the attribute names versus instance fields and the direct serialized form of the class will be significantly different. If you use some sort of JSON serialization for example, the map will add a level of hierarchy not there with fields, which may make persistence and serialization more complex. But for so simple a case, with only string fields each that map to a single attribute with no validation, the hashmap is the superior choice.